# How to display a custom DisplayMember in a ComboBox of Objects (namely Locales)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, locale

I have the follow code set up to feed the list of locales available to .NET within a comboBox.

```
Dim CurrencyList As List(Of CultureInfo) = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).ToList

cboCurrencyLocale.DataSource = CurrencyList
cboCurrencyLocale.DisplayMember = "DisplayName"
cboCurrencyLocale.ValueMember = "Name"
```

Currently this sets up the ComboBox control to display the "DisplayName" property and use the "Name" property as the value. I wanted to know if there is a way to set this up so that the DisplayMember Property shows "English (United States) [en-us]"

I tried to change `cboCurrencyLocale.DisplayMember` line to `cboCurrencyLocale.DisplayMember = "DisplayName" * "Name"` but the combobox still only showed the basic "`DisplayName`" property.

So how can I code this ComboBox to display a custom DisplayMember

Answer (score 1):

An example using a class the inherits CultureInfo.

Inheriting from the CultureInfo class, you can add a new Property that returns a String formatted as you prefer. In this case, patching together the `DisplayName` and `Name` Properties of the base class.

The derived class needs to provide at least one Constructor that matches a Constructor of the base class. In this case, the Constructor that accepts an Integer value, corresponding to the `LCID` Property seems appropriate.

You should also override `ToString()` in the derived class, to match the value returned by the custom Property, in case this same format is need somewhere else, when data binding is not possible.

```
Private Class MyCultureInfo
    Inherits CultureInfo

    Public Sub New(cultureId As Integer)
        MyBase.New(cultureId)
    End Sub

    Public Property MyDisplayMember As String = $"{MyBase.DisplayName} [{MyBase.Name}]"

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return MyDisplayMember
    End Function
End Class
```

To build a `List(Of MyCultureInfo)`, initialize a new List passing a collection of this Type to the constructor that accepts an IEnumerable.
The source of this collection comes from `CultureInfo.GetCultures()`.

```
Dim currencyList As New List(Of MyCultureInfo)(
    CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).
    OrderBy(Function(d) d.DisplayName).
    Select(Function(c) New MyCultureInfo(c.LCID))
)

cboCurrencyLocale.DataSource = Nothing
cboCurrencyLocale.DisplayMember = "MyDisplayName"
cboCurrencyLocale.ValueMember = "Name"
cboCurrencyLocale.DataSource = currencyList
```

Comment: I'm curious about one thing, how come you have to set the Data source to nothing?

Comment: The DataSource is always set to `null`, explicitly, before a new source of data is specified. This clears the internal buffer(s) and resets the DisplayMember. As you can see, I'm setting the Control's properties in the proper order: DisplayMember, ValueMember, then DataSource. This is the sequence that the [internal procedure](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,741) is expecting. If you don't follow this pattern, it will be forced internally, with a twist. When you set the DataSource before the DisplayMember, [...]

Comment: the DisplayMember is cleared, the existing DataSource unwired and reset, then the new DataSource is wired. When you set the DisplayMember after, the DataSource needs to be unwired again and reset again. This can happen a third time, when the ValueMember is changed, if this is what is determined, internally, to be the best course of action, based on the current state. To prevent this, you set the DataSource to null, which resets the CurrencyManager, then set DisplayMember and ValueMember. The DataSource at this point is null, so no action is needed. [...]

Comment: Then set the DataSource with a valid DisplayMember, so the operation is performed just once instead of two or three times. -- When the DataSource doesn't have a lot of data to bind, you probably won't notice the difference. A different story when you have quite a lot data to wire to the CurrencyManager. [This can also cause exceptions](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,77) (see the notes in the source code) in specific cases or simply a lot of unnecessary work to perform the sequence of operations in the correct order.

Comment: BTW, I've added `OrderBy()` to the procedure that generates the list of CultureInfo names, as it should be ordered. -- Note that each Item of the ComboBox can be read both as a MyCultureInfo and a CultureInfo object.